# Debugging 2D vector in Codeblocks

Tags: c++, gdb, codeblocks, stdvector

Is there any way to see values of 2D vector in Watches window using GDB debugger in Code::Blocks IDE under Windows? (Using C::B-13.12 and Win7-64bit)

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector< vector<int> > vec2D (2, vector<int> (3,7));
    ;
}
```

Comment: If you use MinGW, there is a way to print nice values. It's called "pretty print". You must initialize gdb with C:\MinGW\etc\gdbinit. I can't remember better though...

Comment: set print pretty on is the command. But it does not work very well with template(STL type containers) type programs.

Comment: Yes, it prints vector values just fine, but not for vector of vectors. Anyway, please check, maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to show! go to Settings -> Debugger -> Default -> Disable startup scripts need to disable.

Comment: This worked for me and also made the watch window more clear for other types such as string. To be clear: you need to uncheck the box.